# Improve performance for retrieve observable array with knockout and Ajax

Tags: arrays, ajax, knockout.js, observable

I'm retrieving an observable array from Ajax but the performance is being so slow for load the data on a table. could you recommend me another way, please?

Here is my code:

```
self.array = ko.observableArray();
$.get("@Url.Action("Method", "Data")", { id: id })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        viewModel.array(data);
});
```

Comment: You are not retrieving an observable array from Ajax. In fact, you are retrieving data from your server by sending a request by using the Ajax and then you assign that retrieved data into an observable array. So here we need more information like how large is your data? if your data is large you might need to go with concepts like `lazy loading` or `pagination` depends on how you have your design

Comment: Large tables are known to be slow in Knockout. You might want to use this plugin: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-table